# Matlab Kinect Depth Imaging

Tags: matlab, kinect, depth-testing

I'm working with the kinect camera and trying to display real-life depth imaging using the ptCloud method combining the RGB and Depth Sensor. However just using the initial setup my image is disfigured missing pertinent information, is there anyway to improve this so that it captures more data. I have also attached an image of what i mean. Any help would be great thank you!
[image: live video image data]

```
colorDevice = imaq.VideoDevice('kinect',1)
depthDevice = imaq.VideoDevice('kinect',2)
step(colorDevice);
step(depthDevice);
colorImage = step(colorDevice);`enter code here`
depthImage = step(depthDevice);
gridstep = 0.1;
ptCloud = pcfromkinect(depthDevice,depthImage,colorImage);

player = pcplayer(ptCloud.XLimits,ptCloud.YLimits,ptCloud.ZLimits,...
    'VerticalAxis','y','VerticalAxisDir','down');

xlabel(player.Axes,'X (m)');
ylabel(player.Axes,'Y (m)');
zlabel(player.Axes,'Z (m)');
for i = 1:1000    
   colorImage = step(colorDevice);  
   depthImage = step(depthDevice);

   ptCloud = pcfromkinect(depthDevice,depthImage,colorImage);
   ptCloudOut = pcdenoise(ptCloud);
   view(player,ptCloudOut);
end

release(colorDevice);
release(depthDevice);
```

Comment: What information is it missing?

Comment: It's not missing any information, im just trying to improve it so that it displays more data from the device as its missing a large part of data as you can see from the image

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the image, you are trying to capture a cabinet with a TV screen in the middle. In cases like these, the TV screen actually absorbs the IR emitted from the sensor or reflects it at oblong angles/multiple reflections etc. Therefore Kinect is unable to capture the depth data. Furthermore, since when you want to display the RGB data on top of the point cloud, it tries to align the two and rejects any depth data that is not aligned with the RGB image pixels.

So in order to improve your depth data acquisition, you could either take care that there are no reflective surfaces like screen, mirrors etc in the scene. Also, try displaying the depth data without the RGB overlay, which will hopefully improve the point cloud shown.